# Mysql FULL TEXT search Issue

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I’m trying to create a `FULLTEXT` SEARCH of a table. Mysql returns

```
The used table type doesn’t support FULLTEXT indexes.
```

I searched over Internet and found that  [MyISAM is the only type of table that Mysql supports for Full-text indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-restrictions.html). So I've tried to change the type from `InnoDb to MyISAM`. Now, the problem is I've defined foreign key constraints in my tables which are supported by the `InnoDb` Engine.

So, I don't know how to implement `FULLTEXT` search on this InnoDB engine. Please suggest me how to implement `FULLTEXT` search on a table that contains foreign key constraints. (Or) Is any other Engine that supports `FULLTEXT` search on a foreign key constraint's table?

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve  `FAST FULLTEXT` searches is by using `Sphinx` and i also think `MySQL 5.6` supports FULLTEXT indexing with InnoDB .